# At what point of the morning service does one switch from wearing Rashi to wearing Rabenu Tam tefillin?

Tags: tefilin, shacharis-morning-prayer

Many Jews have the custom to wear tefillin according to the opinion of Rashi with a blessing, remove them, and then switch to wearing tefillin according to the opinion of Rabenu Tam without reciting a blessing on them. At what point of the morning service should one switch from wearing Rashi to wearing Rabenu Tam tefillin?

Comment: Please note that it's not a universal custom to put on Rabbeinu Tam tefillin, in the past it was only done by the most pious, and in Ashkenaz most such people refrained from wearing them in public.

Comment: After shacharis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in סימן כה׳ סעיף יג׳ states that the Minhag is to wear the Tefilin until after קדושת ובא לציון. The Mishna Berura quotes the Arizal to wait till after Aleinu. In סימן לד׳ סעיף ב׳ the Shulchan Aruch states to wear the Tefilin of Rashi until after tefila. There the Mishna berura points back to סימן כה׳ to define what after tefila means. And he adds to not do like those that remove there Rashi Tefilin and put on their Rabeinu Tam during chazaras hashatz.

Comment: Since you quoted the Ari - during Shacharis he wore them both simultaneously (see in Shaar HaKavanos [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'ar_HaKavanot%2C_Sermons_on_Tefillin.6.2?lang=he)).